# Values for which a quotient ring is a field.

Tags: ring-theory

So I'm working what values between 0-6 that the quotient ring $F_7/(x^3 -c)$ is a field.

I understand that the quotient ring will be a field if $x^3 - c$ is irreducible mod $7$ and when it has no roots in $F_7$.

So I began subbing in the values for $c$.

$c=0, x^3-0= x^3$

$c=1, x^3-1= (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$

$c=2, x^3-2$ .... no solution

$c=3, x^3-3$ .... no solution

$c=4, x^3-4$ .... no solution

$c=5, x^3-5$ .... no solution

$c=6, x^3-6$ .... no solution

Therefore, $F_7[x]/(x^3 - c)$ is only a field when $c=0$ or $c=1$.

Is this correct? If not please tell me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: You should take a look at our [markup crash course](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) . It's easy and makes things much better.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, $x^3-6$ has roots $\{3,5,6\}$ mod $7$, and that is how it factors: $x^3-6=(x-3)(x-5)(x-6)$ mod $7$.

Other than that, you analysis would tell you that $0, 1$ and $6$ are the only values it *isn't * a field (it looks like you concluded the opposite.)

---

Considering when it has a root in the field is the right way to go though.

What you'll find is that if you cube the elements of $F_7$, you'll always get $0$, $1$ or $6$ as a residue.

So if $c$ is anything other than those three elements, it is impossible for $x^3-c$ to have a root.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for the help. I think i got a little confused along the way. Thank you!!!